# DISTINCT ON with a One to Many Relation through another table

Tags: postgresql

I have four Postgres tables:

#### Professions

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | profession 1 |
| 345 | profession 2 |

#### Versions

| id | professionId | status | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 567 | 123 | Live | 2020-01-01 |
| 999 | 123 | Draft | 2021-02-01 |
| 666 | 345 | Live | 2021-01-01 |

#### Organisations

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 333 | organisation 1 |
| 444 | organisation 2 |
| 655 | organisation 3 |

#### ProfessionToOrganisation

| id | professionId | organisationId | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 665 | 123 | 333 | Regulator |
| 533 | 123 | 444 | Something else |
| 534 | 345 | 444 | Regulator |

I am trying to get the latest version of each profession, regardless of their status, so am using a combination of `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (
    professionVersions.professionId,
    professions.name
  ) professionVersions.id AS "professionVersions_id", professions.name, organisations.name 
FROM professionVersions
    LEFT JOIN professions ON professions.id = professionVersions.professionId
    LEFT JOIN professionToOrganisation ON 
professionToOrganisation.professionId = professions.id
    LEFT JOIN organisations ON professionToOrganisation.organisationId = organisations.id
ORDER BY
    professions.name,
    professionVersions.professionId,
    professionVersions.created_at DESC
```

However, I only get one organisation returned for each profession, i.e:

| professionVersions_id | name | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | Profession 1 | Organisation 1 |
| 666 | Profession 2 | Organisation 2 |

Whereas I wouild like:

| professionVersions_id | name | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | Profession 1 | Organisation 1 |
| 999 | Profession 1 | Organisation 2 |
| 666 | Profession 2 | Organisation 2 |

How do I go about achieving this?

I've got a DB Fiddle here - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44iWbw7oyDtVMsQfE45jPA/0

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` requires an `ORDER BY` clause to make any sense.  You need to articulate what the logic is for retaining certain rows, and you haven't done that above.

Comment: Whoops - fixed!